# Using a variable from an ajax response in another form?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a form (`index.php`) that successfully uploads an image file to a server using jquery ajax.
On success, a response is returned from the server (`response.php`)that echo's back the image that was just uploaded.
I now want to add the `$file_name` variable to a second form on `index.php`.
Whilst I can echo out the $file_name I cannot get it to appear in the form.
Can anyone point me in the correct direction to achieve this?

response.php

```
echo '<h3>Preview</h3>';
//output thumbnails
foreach($responses["thumbs"] as $response){
    echo '<img src="'.$config["thumbnail_destination_folder"].$response.'" class="thumbnails" />';
}
//Echo file_name of image
foreach($responses["thumbs"] as $file_name):
    echo "File Name is".$file_name;
endforeach;
```

Second Form on index.php

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="details_form">
    <input name="file_name" value="<?php echo $file_name;?>">
    <button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: How do you get from `response.php` to `index.php` i.e. how do you do the redirect

Comment: Or do you mean you have 2 `<form>`'s in the same page?

Comment: I've got two forms on the same page.

Comment: But it looks like you have more than one `$file_name` as in first snippet you process `$responses["thumbs"]` in an foreach loop. So just process that array again. If it is still in scope

Comment: the $file_name in ur 2nd form doesnt exist cus its not in the foreach loop anymore

Comment: So how can I process the array  $responses["thumbs"] but use the result in my second form? Do I have to pass the result as a json array back to index.php (where my second form is) or can I just echo it out there? Hope I'm making sense.

Comment: Please answer comment number 1

Comment: I'm using a jquery ajax form. here's some if it. $.ajax({
 url : post_url,
 type: "POST",
 data : form_data,
 contentType: false,
 cache: false,
 processData:false,
 mimeType:"multipart/form-data"
}).done(function(res){ //
 $(my_form_id)[0].reset(); //reset form
 $(result_output).html(res); //output response from server